# How to read text file in Logstash pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I have Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana up and running. I am passing `info.txt` file as an input in Elasticsearch pipeline. Logstash is reading the file but logs are not printing and also unable to create index in Elasticsearch.

Below is my log file:

**info.txt**

```
[92m[MyApp][39m [33mInfo[39m    16/3/2022, 4:54:25 pm [92mHello[39m - {}
[92m[MyApp][39m [33mInfo[39m    16/3/2022, 4:54:27 pm [92mHello[39m - {}
[92m[MyApp][39m [33mInfo[39m    16/3/2022, 5:04:31 pm [92mHello[39m - {}
```

Below is my logstash pipeline:

**logstash.conf**

```
input{
 file{
  path => "D:/nest/es-logging-example/log/info/*.txt"
  start_position => beginning
  sincedb_path => "NULL"
 }
}
output{
 elasticsearch{
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "myapplogs"
 }
 stdout{}
}
```

Below is logstash output on doing `logstash -f logstash.conf`

```
[2022-03-16T16:41:11,277][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch Output 
configured with `ecs_compatibility => v8`, which resolved to an UNRELEASED preview of version 
8.0.0 of the Elastic Common Schema. Once ECS v8 and an updated release of this plugin are 
publicly available, you will need to update this plugin to resolve this warning.
[2022-03-16T16:41:11,277][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant 
with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
[2022-03-16T16:41:11,310][INFO ][logstash.filters.csv     ][main] ECS compatibility is enabled 
but `target` option was not specified. This may cause fields to be set at the top-level of the 
event where they are likely to clash with the Elastic Common Schema. It is recommended to set 
the `target` option to avoid potential schema conflicts (if your data is ECS compliant or non- 
conflicting, feel free to ignore this message)
[2022-03-16T16:41:11,395][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping 
template {:es_version=>8, :ecs_compatibility=>:v8}
[2022-03-16T16:41:11,505][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline 
{:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, 
"pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, "pipeline.sources"=>["D:/logstash- 
8.1.0/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x224314a3 run>"}
[2022-03-16T16:41:13,051][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution 
initialization time {"seconds"=>1.53}
[2022-03-16T16:41:13,153][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started 
{"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2022-03-16T16:41:13,244][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main] 
[c87aefd48e4743b9f32dad848c60392fc5da55d4cdae1e2d620707d1802f9cdf] START, creating Discoverer, 
Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2022-03-16T16:41:13,285][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, 
:running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: it will have created data folder, so delete data folder from logstash directory and start running again logstash pipeline.

Comment: Why data folder needs to be deleted

Comment: After running logstash it has again created data folder inside directory.

Comment: logstash create data folder persistence needs . so sometime due to persitence also it not crawl file. thats why ask to delete data folder and check.

Comment: yeah i did that but again not reading the logs.

Comment: If you set `sincedb_path => "NULL"` then logstash will persist the in-memory sincedb to a file called NULL in its working directory. If you do not want the sincedb persisted across restarts then set it to `NUL`, not `NULL`.

Comment: But its not reading the `txt` file which you can see I have passed as an input in logstash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set: sincedb_path => "/dev/null" and not "NULL" in the input, if you want to reread the file.

Comment: `/dev/null` is needed in linux system and I am using windows so it should be `NULL`.